# How to describe an object with alternative structures / entries in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I'm using TypeScript to work with animation data, and I'm trying to create a `Keyframe` interface (or some other way to tell TypeScript about the shape of a keyframe).

A `Keyframe` might be one of three different configurations:

- those animating only transform properties
- those animating only non-transform properties
- those mixing both.

#### Keyframes might look like this:

```js
const transformKeyframe = {
  'easing': { 'translateX': 'easeInOutQuad' },
  'transform': { 'translateX': '10px' }
} 

const propertyKeyframe = {
  'easing': { 'opacity': 'linear' },
  'opacity': '0.5' 
} 

const mixedKeyframe = {
  'easing': {
    'translateX': 'easeInOutQuad',
    'translateY': 'easeInOutQuad',
    'opacity:': 'linear',
    'fill:': 'linear'
  },
  'transform': {
    'translateX': '10px',
    'translateY': '10px',
  },
  'opacity:': '0.5',
  'fill:': 'red'
} 

const finalKeyframe = {
{
  'easing': { },
  'opacity': '0.5' 
} 
}
```

A Keyframe:

- **always** has an `easing` object, which will either be empty, or contain `[key: string]: string` entries. These keys will always be one of the ~200 animatable CSS properties, in camelCase.
- **sometimes** has a `transform` object, containing `[key: string]: string` entries. These keys will always be one of the 18 CSS transform properties, in camelCase.
- **sometimes** has `[property]` key:value pairs. These keys will always be one of the ~200 animatable CSS properties (excluding the 18 transform properties), and will **never** be the strings `'easing'` or `'transform'`
- **always** has *either* the `transform` object, or at least one `[property]` key:value pair.

What I have been trying is something like this:

```js
interface KeyFrame {
  easing: Record<string, string>;
  transform?: Record<string, string>;
  [property: string]: string;
}
```

One apparent problem is that because `'easing'` and `'transform'` fit the pattern of being string keys, they are interpreted as an instance of `[property: string]: string;`, which causes an error because their values are not of type `string`. At least, I think that's what's happening..?

I'm new to Typescript, and may be missing something obvious, but I can't find the answer to this in the handbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't really possible with index signatures, by defining `[property: string]: string`, TS is really expecting all values to match. The workaround is a union `[property: string]: string | Record<string, string>`, but this is very often not what is desired.

TypeScript comes with a built-in type called `CSSStyleDeclaration` which will have all the keys you want, I think...

We'll intersect all the possible keys, with our own `easing` and `transform` values. I couldn't find a similar built-in list for transform values, so we'll keep that `Record<string, string>`

```js
type KeyFrame = Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> & {
  easing: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>
  transform?: Record<string, string>
}
```

[View this on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDEBOBDAttAvFACipwAligDYA8AwgMo2gkQAiEAxifikQPYB2AfFADIoAbwCwAKChQIKAM6FuAcwBcufEVKUaVOoxZtUXPhKnBU3WQDNOSNAH5VAJRY2AJmVlmFigDRRPSN68EgC+EhLMPJ5QAPqqcIioGFDYYuIA9OlSAHp2JtJy3qpp+WHiZUA)

We have to use a type alias, because `CSSStyleDeclaration` already has a transform key/value configured, but it's set to `string`. So we can overwrite using a type alias and [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)